# Is there any multiline commenting support for C/C++ languages in Atom Editor?

Tags: c++, c, atom-editor, comments

I'd like to enable multi line commenting support in my Atom editor. I'd like the editor to automatically add a `*` and a proper indentation at the beginning of new lines of a multiline comment. Here's a sample of what I'm looking for:

```
/***
 * This is a comment
 * when I'm adding a new line it automatically adds " * ".
 */
```

I've tried to look for such package in the Atom package search, on the SO and google but I failed to find anything. I must have typed wrong key words.
I know that geany editor has such a feature so I guess that Atom has one as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I didn't know that the keyswords should be `block comment`.

I managed to find an excellent extension which is described as *a helper package for writting documentation*.

One way or another it does what I was looking for. 
Here is a link to the repo: https://github.com/nikhilkalige/docblockr